# Error while installing "materializecss" with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, materialize

I'm trying to install `materialize-css` with `npm`:

> npm install materialize-css --save-dev

But I get the following error:

> 2887 error node v4.2.4
>   2888 error npm  v2.14.12
>   2889 error code EPEERINVALID
>   2890 error peerinvalid The package es6-shim@0.33.13 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
>   2890 error peerinvalid Peer angular2@2.0.0-beta.17 wants es6-shim@^0.35.0

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the entire npm package folder and re running npm install?

Comment: @FabrizioMigotto No, let me give it a try!

Comment: @FabrizioMigotto I deleted the entire `node_modules` and reinstalled everything from scratch, and materialize was installed this time :)

Comment: Great, answer posted @Meysam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete the entire `node_modules` folder and re run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have es6-shim version 0.33.13 installed and angular2 version 2.0.0-beta.17 wants a higher version (specifically 0.35.0 or higher).  You need to update that package (es6-shim) to at least that version to satisfy the dependency

Comment: Isn't `npm` meant to handle those dependencies?

Comment: It all depends on how the package lists the dependencies, it doesn't have to install them, which is where you can run into version conflicts.  Do you have the es6-shim package specifically listed in your `package.json`

Comment: No I don't have it in package.json. I deleted the entire `node_modules` and reinstalled everything from scratch, and materialize was installed this time :)

Comment: then you just had a conflicting version already installed, easy fix!